# Make form to show multiple field widgets with predefined values

Tags: entities

I have a node form with multivalue field (cardinality unlimited). I need to show user 3 widgets if this field with predefined value (like shown at screenshot).

At screenshots I show the current form, and its desired look.

How can I achieve this result?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to [build a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7) that calls [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and insert your required pre-filled values before the form is rendered.

Your function should look something like this:

```
<?php

/*
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    // Install devel module and uncomment below to see the variables in the form printed on the screen
    // dpm($form_state);

    // Once you know where to put the variables you can add new values to the field array like this
    $form_state['values']['field_something_important'][] = 'First thing';
    $form_state['values']['field_something_important'][] = 'Second thing';
    $form_state['values']['field_something_important'][] = 'Third thing';
}
```

Note that the actual location to put the values will be different, and might be a few levels deeper into `$form_state`.

As always when making modules:

- Replace the 'hook' part of a function name with the module name (case sensitive)
- Make sure you have the right form id in the hook
- Clear your cache so Drupal can find the hook

Comment: But how can I update the form to show up these filled values? In the initial state, a see empty $form_state['values'] array. Then I put there my values, but they dont appear at form display.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have updated this answer with a solution. I am not 100% that this is what you wanted but hopefully it will get you close.

```
function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // test array
  $items = array(
    'item1',
    'item2',
    'item3',
  );
  // Make sure the fields are in their original or blank state.
  if (!isset($form_state['build_info']['args'][0]->field_YOUR_FIELD[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) && !isset($form_state['default_fields'])) {
    for ($i = 0, $count = count($items); $i < $count; $i++) {
    // First field is already in form.
      if ($i > 0) {
        $form['field_YOUR_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i] = $form['field_YOUR_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0];
      }

      // Set form values
      $form['field_YOUR_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['value']['#default_value'] = $items[$i];
      $form['field_YOUR_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['value']['#value'] = $items[$i];

      // Set row weight
     $form['field_YOUR_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$i]['_weight'] = array(
      '#type' => 'weight',
      '#title' => t('Weight for row ' . ($i + 1)),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
      '#delta' => $i,
      '#default_value' => $i,
      '#weight' => 100,
     );
    }
    $form_state['default_fields'] = 1;
    $form_state['field']['field_YOUR_FIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['items_count'] = count($items) - 1;
  }
 }
```

This solution probably has some superfluous code. I will try to get some time t edit later. As Darvanen stated your structure and language etc. may be different.

Comment: Its about working with custom form. But I need to control regular core fields added to content type.

Comment: So the first three instances of this field will always be the same, or are the default values modifiable?

Comment: I need to set them programmatically. There may be any number of items with different values. I just need to populate it from code.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear the fields will be editable and there will be more than one node for this content type?

Comment: Yes, user can change prefilled values, add more fields or delete them.

Comment: Updated answer with a solution.

Comment: the code works perfectly. it prepopulates a multivalue field and only shows the needed fields

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to populate values into existing field, try [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

This allows you to pass the values from the URL simulating the user input.

> It allows fields in most forms to be pre-populated from the $_REQUEST variable.

You can also use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) with [Forms Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) to do populate values on certain condition.